# Why I can't load models in modules?! [Using HMVC in codeigniter 2.1.2]

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I hope someone can help me with this one before I jump off the window. I spent few hours on this one and don't know what am I doing wrong.

Basically, I've installed HMVC in CodeIgniter 2.1.2 and everything works fine, BUT for some reason I can't load models the same way I'm doing it in standard controllers. In the old codeigniter 1.7.1 I could use it simply by invoking $this->load->model('my_model') but now I can't?!

Every single time I'm trying to load model I get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Special_cart::$db
Filename: core/Model.php
Line Number: 51
```

I have had installed it step-by-step according to the instructions. I got third_party next to modules folder. In modules I have few modules stored like this:

```
modules
--boxes
----controller
----models
----views
```

I invoke module in my code like this:

```
<?=modules::run('boxes/special_cart/index');?>
```

My module controller code looks like this:

```
class Special_cart extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }   





    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('cart'))
        {
            # get product id's and each quantity

            $cart_product_list = array_count_values($this->session->userdata('cart'));

            # get list of product_id
            $product_list = array_keys($cart_product_list); 

            # get product details
            $this->load->model('productmodel');
            $this->load->model('stockmodel');

            $cart_products = $this->productmodel->cart_get_products_details($product_list);
            $final_cart_array = array();

            foreach($cart_products as $cart_product){
                $product_stock = $this->stockmodel->view_product_stock($cart_product["id"]);
                if(empty($product_stock) || $product_stock["UNITS"]<=0)
                    $cart_product["UNITS"] = 0;
                else{
                    if($cart_product_list[$cart_product["id_web"]]>$product_stock["UNITS"])
                        $cart_product["UNITS"] = $product_stock["UNITS"];
                    else{
                        $cart_product["UNITS"] = $cart_product_list[$cart_product["id_web"]];
                    }
                }
                $final_cart_array[] = $cart_product;

            }

            $refresh_cart_array = array();


            foreach($final_cart_array as $cart_product){

                for($i=1;$i<=$cart_product["UNITS"];$i++){
                    $refresh_cart_array[] = $cart_product["id_web"];
                }

            }


            $this->load->view("special_cart",array(
                                                'refresh_cart_array'        => $refresh_cart_array,
                                                'final_cart_array' => $final_cart_array
                                                ));





                } else {
                $this->load->view("special_cart",array(
                                                    'refresh_cart_array'        => NULL,
                                                    'final_cart_array' => NULL
                                                    ));

                    }
            }   

}
```

I've tried every possible solution found on internet - none of them work.... 
I hope you understand my problem but in case you need some further explanation please ask me. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the model you're trying to load wants to connect to the db, but the database driver is not available. If you use database queries in your application, why don't you load the database driver automatically?

Just insert "database" in the "libraries" array in application/config/autoload.php file. Don't forget to insert your database credentials into application/config/database.php.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

If you need database connection just in one single model, load it before trying to access database library.

```
$this->load->database();
```

Comment: This is what I have in my config file: $autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database','form_validation','email','redux_auth');. I also tried to load the database you mentioned in a single model but didn't work as well :/ Could there be some bug in HMVC cores?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use extend MX_Controller class (not CI_Contoller like you are doing atm)

Based on what you have wrote in comment above, I figured that you tried to create new instance of DB in module (based on chrises comment).
Do it on constuctor of Special_cart

So update current construct to be like

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database('default');
}
```

(I'm writing this from top of my head, so check the methods)

Now for sure db driver should be available in your models.

Regarding issue with `HMVC` I dont think there are any. I'm using `HMVC` for a while now, and I found no problems in it (working with databases)

Comment: But should the db driver not also has been loaded when inserting into the autoload config? With that, the db driver should be ready even in model's constructor, shouldn't it?

Comment: It should, yes. But based on question, it is not the case atm.
From some reason CI is loosing instance of db class when loaded from MX. Not sure why, but from previous experience that is extremly rear situation that code itself lose pointer to another object that was created before. That is why I wrote to try to reload database, and see would it help. But first solution was to change parent class for Special_cart. $this->load->database('default') was just a confirmation that db instance is created and available.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the model stating the module name as follows

```
    $this->load->model('module_name/productmodel');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Models extends MX_Loader{

    function getUser($username){

        $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? ";
        return $this->db->query($sql,array($username))->row();

   } 
}
```

you must using extends MX_Loader because i don't know if using CI_Model the database core cant be load in Codeigniter,,,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and mistake. I missed to extend controllers to MX_Controller. So the solution would be to change CI_Controller to MX_Controller like this:

```
class Special_cart extends MX_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('productmodel');
        $this->load->model('stockmodel'); 
    }

     public function index()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('cart'))
        {
            # get product id's and each quantity

            $cart_product_list = array_count_values($this->session->userdata('cart'));

            # get list of product_id
            $product_list = array_keys($cart_product_list); 

            # get product details

            $cart_products = $this->productmodel->cart_get_products_details($product_list);
            $final_cart_array = array();

            foreach($cart_products as $cart_product){
                $product_stock = $this->stockmodel->view_product_stock($cart_product["id"]);
                if(empty($product_stock) || $product_stock["UNITS"]<=0)
                    $cart_product["UNITS"] = 0;
                else{
                    if($cart_product_list[$cart_product["id_web"]]>$product_stock["UNITS"])
                        $cart_product["UNITS"] = $product_stock["UNITS"];
                    else{
                        $cart_product["UNITS"] = $cart_product_list[$cart_product["id_web"]];
                    }
                }
                $final_cart_array[] = $cart_product;

            }

            $refresh_cart_array = array();


            foreach($final_cart_array as $cart_product){

                for($i=1;$i<=$cart_product["UNITS"];$i++){
                    $refresh_cart_array[] = $cart_product["id_web"];
                }

            }


            $this->load->view("special_cart",array(
                                                'refresh_cart_array'        => $refresh_cart_array,
                                                'final_cart_array' => $final_cart_array
                                                ));





                } else {
                $this->load->view("special_cart",array(
                                                    'refresh_cart_array'        => NULL,
                                                    'final_cart_array' => NULL
                                                    ));

                    }
            } 
}
```

this is also explained in the documentation
https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/
, here the quote:

> Notes:
>
> To use HMVC functionality, such as Modules::run(), controllers must
>   extend the MX_Controller class. To use Modular Separation only,
>   without HMVC, controllers will extend the CodeIgniter Controller
>   class. You must use PHP5 style constructors in your controllers. ie:
>
> ```
> <?php
> class Xyz extends MX_Controller 
> {
>     function __construct()
>     {
>         parent::__construct();
>     }
> }
> ```